# Chef-server-ctl test throwing error "Failed to authenticate"

Tags: chef-infra

When I run chef-server-ctl test, I get the following errors:

```
Pending: (Failures listed here are expected and do not affect your suite's status)

1) opscode-account user association user not in org can be invited to the org by an admin when the inviting annot be accepted
 # Known failure: passes w/ 200 b/c no USAG cleanup performed for deleted user
 # ./spec/api/account/account_association_spec.rb:661

2) opscode-account user association user not in org can be invited to the org by an admin when the inviting a can't by accepted
 # Known failure: passes w/ 200 b/c no USAG or other group cleanup performed for deleted user
 # ./spec/api/account/account_association_spec.rb:670


Failures:

1) authenticate_user POST /authenticate_user with correct credentials superuser user returns 200 ("OK")
 Failure/Error:
   post(request_url, superuser, :payload => body).should look_like({
       :status => 200,
       :body_exact => response_body
     })

   Response should have HTTP status code 200 ('OK'), but it was actually 401 ('Unauthorized')
     Reponse Body: {"error":["Failed to authenticate: Username and password incorrect"]}
 # ./spec/api/authenticate_user_spec.rb:129:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) users /users/<name> endpoint PUT /users/<name> superuser authenticating after updates when password is uncs not been changed.
 Failure/Error:
   post(auth_url, superuser, :payload => { 'username' => username,
                                           'password' => password }).should look_like({
       :status => 200
   })

   Response should have HTTP status code 200 ('OK'), but it was actually 401 ('Unauthorized')
     Reponse Body: {"error":["Failed to authenticate: Username and password incorrect"]}
 # ./spec/api/user_spec.rb:873:in `block (7 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 3 minutes 14.5 seconds (files took 17.5 seconds to load)
154 examples, 2 failures, 2 pending

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/api/authenticate_user_spec.rb:128 # authenticate_user POST /authenticate_user with correct credent
rspec ./spec/api/user_spec.rb:871 # users /users/<name> endpoint PUT /users/<name> superuser authenticating aft modified user when password has not been changed.
```

My chef server authenticates users against AD and I've notices that if I invite an user in an organization, Users gets the invitation, but when to confirm it, he gets the message " There was a problem processing one or more invitations. Please try again later."

Because of that I've decided to test the chef server and the errors output is above.
Could anyone help me understand what is wrong with my chef server settings?

Thank you,

Gabriel

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's Cross posted on chef mailing list here: https://discourse.chef.io/t/chef-server-ctl-test-error/10269 and there's few chances for it to be useful to someone in the future.

Comment: Tensibai, do you have any ideea of what I could have wrong in my settings? Nobody answered me on chef mailing list... and maybe there are people here that can answer my question.

Comment: Absolutely none, but the mailing list is more likely to be of help than SO as it will need a bunch of steps for debugging which paramater is wrong in your chef-server